# Is there a way to search backward in Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets, search

When I click CTRL+H then I can open big search box in Google Spreadsheets. It searches forward for specific text all sheets from the position of my cursor. But is there a way to search backward?

**I want to find last occurrence of specific text in previous sheets**. Maybe is there some kind of formula I could use, since it seems default search box doesn't have function to search backwards.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 2):

The **Edit > Find and replace** dialog box (**Control+Shift+H**) only searches forward, but the quick find dialog box (**Control+F**) lets you search in both directions. Press **Control+G** to go forward and **Control+Shift+G** to go backward.

The **Control+G** shortcut is not listed in the [keyboard shortcuts](http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&p=spreadsheets_shortcuts&answer=181110) help page, but it is fairly common in all kinds of office software.

This method of searching backward only works in the current sheet. To search across all sheets, dedicate a cell such as `A1` on every sheet as a search box. You can make sure that the search box cell is always visible by using **View > Freeze > 1 row** and **View > Freeze > 1 column**.

Then add a script that runs on a [simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers), searches for a text string or [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html), and activates cells that match that string across the spreadsheet.

Here's one way to do that:

```
/**
* Simple trigger that runs each time the user hand edits the spreadsheet.
*
* @param {Object} e The onEdit() event object.
*/
function onEdit(e) {
  if (!e) {
    throw new Error('Please do not run the script in the script editor window. It runs automatically when you hand edit the spreadsheet.');
  }
  quickFind_(e);
}

/**
* Activates cells that match the regular expression entered in a magic cell.
*
* @param {Object} e The onEdit() event object.
*/
function quickFind_(e) {
  // version 1.1, written by --Hyde, 13 March 2023
  //  - activate cells in multiple sheets
  //  - see https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/169771/269219
  // version 1.0, written by --Hyde, 16 May 2021
  //  - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/67555531/13045193

  // specify the sheets where the function will be active
  // use /./i to make the function work in all sheets
  // use /^(Sheet1|Sheet2|Sheet3)$/i to make the function work only those three sheets
  const sheetsToWatch = /./i;
  // specify the location of the magic cell where you enter search strings or regexes
  const magicCellA1 = 'A1';

  let activeSheet;
  let activeSheetName;
  if (!e.value
    || e.range.getA1Notation() !== magicCellA1
    || !(activeSheetName = (activeSheet = e.range.getSheet()).getName()).match(sheetsToWatch)) {
    return;
  }
  e.source.toast(`Searching the spreadsheet for '${e.value}'...`);
  let searchFor;
  try {
    searchFor = new RegExp(e.value, 'i');
  } catch (error) {
    searchFor = e.value.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&');
  }
  const magicCellR1C1 = `R${e.range.rowStart}C${e.range.columnStart}`;
  let numMatches = 0;
  let activeSheetMatches = [];
  e.source.getSheets().forEach(sheet => {
    let sheetName;
    if (!(sheetName = sheet.getName()).match(sheetsToWatch)) {
      return;
    }
    const data = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
    const matches = [];
    data
      .forEach((row, rowIndex) => row
        .forEach((value, columnIndex) => {
          if (value.match(searchFor)) {
            const cellR1C1 = `R${rowIndex + 1}C${columnIndex + 1}`;
            if (cellR1C1 !== magicCellR1C1) {
              matches.push(cellR1C1);
              if (sheetName === activeSheetName) {
                activeSheetMatches.push(cellR1C1);
              }
            }
          }
        }));
    if (matches.length) {
      sheet.getRangeList(matches).activate();
      numMatches += matches.length;
    }
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  });
  if (activeSheetMatches.length) {
    activeSheet.getRangeList(activeSheetMatches).activate();
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  }
  e.source.toast(`Done. Found ${numMatches} matches for '${e.value}'.`, 'Search complete', 10);
}
```

Type the search string or regular expression in cell `A1`. The script will activate cells that match that string. To jump from one matching cell to another, press **Tab** to advance and **Shift+Tab** to back up. Switch to another tab to see the matches there.

Comment: Thank you for that advice, but this small search box allows you to search only in current sheet. I want to find last occurrence of specific text in previously created sheets.

Comment: Edited the answer to add a scripted solution.